# PHP Get next row that fits parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying ads in between listings in a table. I need to be able to display a different ad in each space as long as it's in the right category, state and city. I already have the table rows separated by the ads, but with what I have below, I can only show the same ad in all three slots. I'm looking for help in figuring out how to display different ads for each slot, or display a placeholder if there are no more ads in that category. The code that I have is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state);
    $myBanners = null;
    $advert = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Advertisements WHERE category='$type' AND city='$city' AND state='$state' LIMIT 1");
    $banner = mysql_fetch_object($advert);
    if (empty($banner)){
        $placeholder = "<tr><td colspan='3'><div class='well' style='padding: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;'><a href='advertise.php'><img src='uploads/AdPH.jpg' width='100%'></a></div></td></tr>";
        } else {
        while($banner = mysql_fetch_object($advert))
        {
          $myBanners[] = $banner;
          $placeholder = "<tr><td colspan='3'><div class='well' style='padding: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;'><a href='$myBanners[]->website'><img src='$myBanners[]->img' width='100%'></a></div></td></tr>";
        }

        }


    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Businesses WHERE type='$type' AND city='$city' AND state='$state' ORDER BY upvotes DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
            $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
            if(($i%3) == 0)
        {
            // The code right here will only run when $i / 3  is exactly 0 (3,6,9,etc)
            echo $placeholder;
        }
            $i++;
```

Now I'm getting an error for the brackets [] in the $placeholder variable for the while statement.

Comment: DISTINCT * (on a single table) is (or at least 'should be') meaningless

Comment: Also, note that this is code from the last decade. We just don't do it this way anymore. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot get all of the result in a single function call, you should
do it in a `while()` loop.
You should do this:

```
//....
// First declare a variable to store all results
$myBanners = null;

$advert = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Advertisements WHERE category='$type' AND city='$city' AND state='$state' LIMIT 1");

while($banner = mysql_fetch_object($advert))
{
  $myBanners[] = $banner;
}
//...
```

Note that you should fetch all of the results in a while loop.

A side note:
Please don't use mySQL driver as it is officially deprecated. It is for sure better to use MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: I edited my question to show the change that you suggested, but now I'm getting an error for the brackets.

Comment: well, it is a syntax error. Is your problem now solved?